# Reading small parts of a text file into a text field in GUI

Tags: java, text-files, jtextfield, bufferedreader, stringtokenizer

Im going to write a hotel reservation program for my final year at school. I am going to use a text file to have all the guests whose attributes include: Name, Surname, contact details etc. and I want to read these attributes back to the text fields they were entered in to but they will be the same fields and labels and everything but in a different page. I will be using a StringTokenizer when writing to the file so there will be e.g. a '#' separating each attribute.

Can someone please help with reading each attribute separately into separate text fields so e.g. the text file will look something like this:

Sam#Haden#samhaden@gmail.com#7562234#

and I want each attribute to be read to a separate text field.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and what's not working.

Comment: Write some code first and if you run into trouble post it here. Best way to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use String.indexOf("#") to find a hash tag, then use that index to create a substring with just the first element, and a substring of the remaining elements. Then repeat the process until everything is split into the separate text fields.

Comment: How about String#split() method?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: your comment is better than smoothButter's answer, and I think that you should make this comment an answer.

Comment: Totally forgot about that. I agree, Ravi's answer is a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
split('#')
```

it would return an array... read from the different indexes to populate the fields.

Answer (score 1):

you could consider to use Splitter from google-guava library like this:

```
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;

Iterable<String> fieldset = Splitter.on("#").split("Sam#Haden#samhaden@gmail.com#7562234#");

for(final String s : fieldset) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

access fields by index:

```
Iterables.get(fieldset, 2); // returns "samhaden"
```

Comment: Thanks Steve Oh ill try this. I was just planning my program when I wanted to know if this was not such a hard task to do. It seems decent. I havent written any code yet. Also only doing my design now for my project

Comment: I just tried to import the guava library it says it doesnt exist